# Proving uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ under some conditions on $\{f_n'\}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)$ is a sequence of continuous differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n(0)=0$, $|f^{\prime}_n(x)|\le x^{-1/2}$ a.e., and there exists $h$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{\prime}_n(x)=h(x)$ for all $x$. Prove that there is an absolutely continuous function $f$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

I think $f=\int_0^xh(t)dt$, and we know that $h$ is integrable by given conditions. Also, $f$ is absolutely continuous by fundamental theorem of calculus. $f_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n^{\prime}(t)dt$ as $f_n$ is continuous differentiable and $f_n(0)=0$. Our goal is to show that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\int_0^xf_n^{\prime}(t)-h(t)dt|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Why do you say a.e. when the derivatives are continuous functions?

Comment: @zhw.This is an exercise I saw somewhere, and now I think there may be a typo for this problem. If we require $f_n$ to be only differentiable, then a.e. do make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in [0,1]$,

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \left|\int_0^x f_n'(t) - h(t) dt\right| \le \int_0^x |f_n' - h| \le \int_0^1 |f_n' - h|.$$
$$\Rightarrow \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)|\le \int_0^1 |f_n' - h|.$$
The Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem applied to the sequence $\{f_n'\}$ (note $|f_n'(x)| \le x^{-1/2}$ and $x^{-1/2}$ is integrable) implies that

$$\int_0^1 |f_n' - h| \to 0$$

as $n\to \infty$. Thus

$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 0$$

as $n\to \infty$ and so the convergence is uniform.

Comment: So, actually we do not need the condition that $|f_n^{\prime}(x)|\le x^{-1/2}$? Since, $f_n^{\prime}$ is continuous it will be bounded on $[0,1]$ and therefore we can apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. I guess there may be a typo for this problem. What if we only require $f_n$ to be differentiable? I think $f_n^{\prime}$ is bounded by integrable function almost everywhere will then be not enough for us to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: The above condition is why we can use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem on the sequence $\{f_n'\}$. @Syoung I've edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: If $|f_n^{\prime}(x)|\le x^{-1/2}$ holds only almost everywhere(and if we only require $f_n$ to be differentiable), is it enough to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? I remember that Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem requires the sequence is dominated by integrable function everywhere.

Comment: Only almost everywhere is needed. @Syoung . Almost every theorem in real analysis are interpreted this way.

Comment: Now I agree with you. That is the point confused me. Thanks.